# Selecting path element fill with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have some outer `g` element and an inner element with a green fill colour that is part of a maps SVG path. I've managed to select the inner path element, but am unable to select its fill attribute to get its colour. How can I select the first inner path element's fill colour?

Selecting the first path element:

```
var item = $('.datamap path')
```

And my attempt to get the fill, which yields the following exception:

```
$(item).attr('fill')
```

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object SVGPathElement]' is not a valid selector.

Here's what my DOM looks like:

```
<g id="" class="datamaps-subunits">
  <path d="M335.2035703570357,117.04432210343535L336.6065106510651,117.58613066703171L337.6587158715872,117.39767551447646L337.95934593459344,116.76163937460245L339.06165616561657,116.54962732797782L339.8132313231323,116.12560323472849L340.11386138613864,115.01842921346635L341.2662766276628,114.75930337870288L341.51680168016804,114.26460860324534L342.1681668166817,114.61796201428643L342.5690069006901,114.66507580242525L343.37068706870684,114.68863269649465L344.37278727872786,114.97131542532753L344.82373237323736,115.13621368381338L345.8258325832584,114.68863269649465L346.27677767776777,114.97131542532753L346.7277227722773,114.33527928545355L347.5795079507951,114.35883617952294L347.7799279927993,114.1468241328983L347.93024302430246,113.58145867523254L348.531503150315,113.11032079384438L349.2830783078308,113.41656041674668L349.13276327632764,113.840584509996L349.5837083708371,113.91125519220422L349.433393339334,115.0890998956746L349.9845484548455,115.53668088299332L350.485598559856,115.25399815416041L351.0868586858686,115.11265678974398L351.93864386438645,114.47662064987L352.8906390639064,114.59440512021703L354.34368436843687,114.59440512021703L354.5942094209421,114.99487231939695L353.7925292529253,115.13621368381338L353.09105910591063,115.39533951857686L351.487698769877,115.56023777706272L349.9845484548455,115.86647739996499L349.1828682868287,116.45539975170018L349.483498349835,117.04432210343535L349.6839183918392,117.75102892551756L348.98244824482447,118.33995127725274L349.0325532553255,118.8582029467797L348.63171317131713,119.37645461630663L347.32898289828984,119.32934082816783L347.8801380138014,120.24805969687469L346.9782478247825,120.60141310791579L346.3769876987699,121.42590440034505L346.477197719772,122.27395258684369L345.92604260426043,122.6508628919542L345.4249924992499,122.53307842160717L344.32268226822686,122.72153357416242L344.1723672367237,123.09844387927293L343.1702670267027,123.09844387927293L342.3685868586859,123.89937827763278L342.31848184818483,125.07722298110312L340.51470147014703,125.64258843876888L339.5627062706271,125.52480396842185L339.2620762076208,125.83104359132413L338.46039603960395,125.66614533283828L337.05745574557454,125.85460048539355L334.70252025202524,125.14789366331132L335.9551455145515,123.89937827763278L335.85493549354936,123.0042163029953L334.8027302730273,122.76864736230124L334.70252025202524,121.87348538766378L334.2515751575158,120.76631136640165L334.85283528352835,120.01249075618061L334.2515751575158,119.80047870955596L334.6023102310231,118.78753226457147Z" class="datamaps-subunit AFG" style="fill: rgb(171, 221, 164); stroke-width: 1px; stroke: rgb(253, 253, 253);">
  </path>

  <path d="M283.29477947794777,181.87289458244325L283.44509450945094,182.29691867569258L283.24467446744677,182.98006860370538L283.495199519952,183.63966163764877L283.29477947794777,184.1579133071757L283.44509450945094,184.62905118856384L280.53900390039,184.60549429449446L280.43879387938796,189.03419037954296L281.3907890789079,190.18847818894392L282.2926792679268,191.06008326951195L279.7373237323732,191.6254487271777L276.3802880288029,191.41343668055305L275.42829282928295,190.75384364660965L269.76642664266427,190.82451432881788L269.5660066006601,190.91874190509552L268.71422142214226,190.28270576522152L267.81233123312336,190.2355919770827L267.0106510651065,190.47116091777679L266.3091809180918,190.75384364660965L266.2089708970897,189.8586816719722L266.40939093909395,188.65728007443244L266.8603360336034,187.36165090061505L266.96054605460546,186.7727285488799L267.4114911491149,185.52421316320132L267.7121212121212,184.95884770553556L268.51380138013803,184.04012883682867L268.9647464746475,183.4276495910241L269.11506150615065,182.39114625197018L269.0649564956496,181.59021185361036L268.6140114011401,181.09551707815282L268.26327632763275,180.24746889165417L267.9125412541254,179.4229775992249L268.0127512751275,179.14029487039204L268.4135913591359,178.57492941272628L268.0127512751275,177.2321864507701L267.7121212121212,176.3134675820632L267.0106510651065,175.41830560742574L267.1609660966097,175.15917977266227L267.7121212121212,174.970724620107L268.1129612961296,174.9942815141764L268.6140114011401,174.82938325569057L272.72262226222625,174.85294014975997L273.0733573357336,175.88944348881387L273.474197419742,176.71393478124313L273.77482748274826,177.16151576856186L274.3259825982598,177.89177948471348L275.2278727872787,177.77399501436645L275.6788178817882,177.58553986181118L276.48049804980496,177.77399501436645L276.6809180918092,177.44419849739475L277.0316531653165,176.6197072049655L277.88343834383437,176.57259341682666L277.98364836483654,176.3370244761326L278.6851185118512,176.3134675820632L278.53480348034805,176.83171925159016L280.23837383738373,176.80816235752076L280.2884788478848,177.67976743808882L280.53900390039,178.22157600168518L280.33858385838585,179.0696241881838L280.43879387938796,179.91767237468247L280.8897389738974,180.4359240442094L280.83963396339635,182.08490662906792L281.1903690369037,181.96712215872088L281.7916291629163,181.99067905279028L282.64341434143415,181.80222390023502ZM266.96054605460546,174.73515567941294L266.55970597059707,173.67509544628965L267.1609660966097,173.08617309455445L267.5618061806181,172.8506041538604L268.0628562856286,173.32174203524852L267.5618061806181,173.60442476408141L267.36138613861385,173.9813350691919L267.31128112811285,174.5702574209271Z" class="datamaps-subunit AGO" style="fill: rgb(171, 221, 164); stroke-width: 1px; stroke: rgb(253, 253, 253);">
  </path>

  <path d="M278.63501350135016,108.42249887403241L278.484698469847,108.89363675542054L278.6851185118512,109.48255910715571L279.2362736273627,109.83591251819684L279.2362736273627,110.18926592923793L278.78532853285327,110.4012779758626L278.6851185118512,110.84885896318133L278.03375337533754,111.53200889119412L277.7832283228323,111.41422442084709L277.7832283228323,111.1079847979448L277.031653`1653165,110.66040381062606L276.8813381338134,109.97725388261327L276.98154815481547,109.03497811983698L277.1819681968197,108.61095402658768L276.98154815481547,108.37538508589361L276.8813381338134,107.95136099264428L277.482598259826,107.26821106463146L277.53270327032703,107.52733689939494L277.9335433543354,107.3859955349785L278.23417341734176,107.76290584008902L278.5849084908491,107.90424720450545Z" class="datamaps-subunit ALB" style="fill: rgb(171, 221, 164); stroke-width: 1px; stroke: rgb(253, 253, 253);">
  </path>

  <path d="M321.7754275427543,132.92166870621563L322.0259525952595,132.85099802400742L322.0760576057606,133.2279083291179L323.1783678367837,133.01589628249326L324.33078307830783,133.06301007063206L325.18256825682573,133.0865669647015L326.13456345634563,132.1678480959946L327.13666366636664,131.27268612135714L328.03855385538554,130.40108104078908L328.2890789078908,130.8722189221772L328.489498949895,131.97939294343934L327.78802880288026,131.97939294343934L327.63771377137715,132.89811181214623L327.88823882388243,133.0865669647015L327.2869786978698,133.36924969353436L327.2869786978698,133.93461515120012L326.88613861386136,134.49998060886588L326.8360336033603,135.06534606653165L326.5354035403541,135.34802879536454L322.37668766876686,134.66487886735175L321.82553255325536,133.25146522318732Z" class="datamaps-subunit ARE" style="fill: rgb(171, 221, 164); stroke-width: 1px; stroke: rgb(253, 253, 253);">
  </path>

  <path d="M156.82973297329733,243.07370537476248L155.97794779477948,243.02659158662365L154.47479747974796,243.02659158662365L154.47479747974796,239.91708156946194L155.02595259525953,240.55311770933594L155.72742274227426,241.61317794245923L157.53120312031203,242.43766923488846L159.485298529853,242.7910226459296L158.83393339333935,243.4977294680118L157.53120312031203,243.5448432561506ZM162.74212421242123,197.6324567148765L165.29747974797482,199.89391854553955L166.44989498949894,200.1059305921642L168.15346534653466,201.1424339312181L169.6065106510651,201.6842424948145L169.80693069306932,202.29672174061906L168.4039903990399,204.41684220686568L169.80693069306932,204.7937525119762L171.4102910291029,205.00576455860084L172.51260126012602,204.77019561790678L173.76522652265226,203.71013538478348L173.96564656465648,202.4851768931743L174.66711671167116,202.22605105841083L175.3685868586859,203.0269854567707L175.31848184818483,204.1341594780328L174.16606660666068,204.91153698232324L173.2140714071407,205.476902439989L171.66081608160817,206.8196454019452L169.80693069306932,208.72775382156715L169.45619561956198,209.83492784282927L169.1054605460546,211.2718983810631L169.1054605460546,212.63819823708872L168.8048304830483,212.9679947540604L168.7046204620462,213.86315672869787L168.6044104410441,214.59342044484947L170.35808580858088,215.77126514831983L170.15766576657666,216.73709780516552L171.05955595559556,217.34957705097008L170.95934593459344,218.0327269789829L169.65661566156615,219.79949403418843L167.55220522052207,220.55331464440945L164.7964296429643,220.83599737324232L163.24317431743174,220.6946560088259L163.54380438043805,221.54270419532452L163.24317431743174,222.57920753437844L163.49369936993702,223.28591435646064L162.6920192019202,223.75705223784877L161.23897389738974,223.94550739040403L159.93624362436245,223.4508126149465L159.38508850885088,223.8041660259876L159.58550855085508,225.1940227760826L160.48739873987398,225.61804686933192L161.2890789078908,225.1704658820132L161.6899189918992,225.90072959816482L160.3871887188719,226.32475369141414L159.2848784878488,227.1963587719822L159.08445844584458,228.5862155220772L158.73372337233724,229.34003613229822L157.43099309930994,229.34003613229822L156.32868286828685,230.07029984844985L155.92784278427843,231.10680318750374L157.33078307830783,232.11974963248826L158.63351335133515,232.40243236132113L158.18256825682568,233.6509477469997L156.52910291029104,234.42832525129012L155.62721272127214,236.0773078361486L154.37458745874588,236.61911639974497L153.7733273327333,237.27870943368836L154.22427242724274,238.71567997192219L155.1762676267627,239.516614370282L154.57500750075008,239.44594368807378L153.27227722772278,239.23393164144915L149.9152415241524,239.04547648889388L149.36408640864084,238.24454209053403L149.36408640864084,237.18448185741073L148.46219621962194,237.27870943368836L147.96114611461147,236.78401465823083L147.81083108310833,235.29993033185818L148.9131413141314,234.6874510860536L149.36408640864084,233.81584600548553L149.16366636663668,233.10913918340333L149.9152415241524,231.90773758586357L150.4162916291629,230.07029984844985L150.26597659765974,229.2458085560206L150.86723672367236,228.98668272125713L150.7169216921692,228.46843105173016L150.06555655565558,228.18574832289727L150.56660666066608,227.5968259711621L149.9152415241524,227.07857430163517L149.61461146114613,225.4767055049155L150.16576657665766,225.1940227760826L149.9152415241524,223.4979264030853L150.26597659765974,222.06095586485148L150.6167116711671,220.83599737324232L151.46849684968498,220.31774570371536L151.01755175517553,218.95144584768977L151.01755175517553,217.6793735679418L152.06975697569757,216.78421159330432L152.01965196519654,215.60636688983396L152.82133213321333,214.2636239278778L152.82133213321333,212.9679947540604L152.47059705970597,212.70886891929692L151.81923192319232,210.30606572421743L152.67101710171016,208.892652080053L152.57080708070808,207.5263522240274L153.07185718571856,206.27783683834883L153.97374737473746,204.95865077046204L154.97584758475847,204.11060258396338L154.52490249024902,203.54523712629762L154.82553255325536,203.0976561389789L154.7754275427543,200.789080520177L156.27857785778576,200.1059305921642L156.77962796279627,198.645403159861L156.62931293129313,198.3156066428893L157.78172817281728,197.0435343631413L159.58550855085508,197.39688777418243L160.3871887188719,198.38627732509752L160.93834383438343,197.27910330383537L162.54170417041703,197.3262170919742Z" class="datamaps-subunit ARG" style="fill: rgb(171, 221, 164); stroke-width: 1px; stroke: rgb(253, 253, 253);">
  </path>

  <path d="M310.65211521152116,109.48255910715571L312.60621062106213,109.27054706053107L312.85673567356736,109.62390047157217L313.4078907890789,109.85946941226624L313.1072607260726,110.21282282330733L313.85883588358837,110.70751759876488L313.45799579958,111.13154169201421L314.0592559255926,111.50845199712472L314.7106210621062,111.74402093781879L314.7106210621062,112.70985359466448L314.2095709570957,112.75696738280328L313.6584158415842,111.95603298444345L313.6584158415842,111.72046404374937L313.0571557155715,111.74402093781879L312.60621062106213,111.36711063270828L312.35568556855685,111.39066752677766L311.80453045304534,110.99020032759776L310.7523252325233,110.63684691655666L310.9026402640264,109.97725388261327Z" class="datamaps-subunit ARM" style="fill: rgb(171, 221, 164); stroke-width: 1px; stroke: rgb(253, 253, 253);">
  </path>
</g>
```

Comment: Get it working in a https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can play with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight multiple path elements within SVG <g> on event action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555254/highlight-multiple-path-elements-within-svg-g-on-event-action)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get css property value you should use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css) not attr

```
var item = $('.datamaps-subunits path');
$(item).css('fill');
```

see it work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/robert11094/ehcjw4ww/1)

Comment: i updated the answer with link to the code that work